# How to display registered customer list as dropdown in WooCommerce checkout?

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic

I am making a plugin so an admin can submit an order on behalf of a customer in Woocommerce. This plugin is suitable for orders placed via phone/email/WhatsApp.

I want to display a list of customer as dropdown in the WooCommerce checkout Page. Only administrators can see this list.

Please help.

Comment: WooCommerce admins can already create orders for customers in the back-end, can't they?

Comment: @JacobPeattie yes dear. But I want this in front-end. In this question I just want to display a list of customer as dropdown in WooCommerce Checkout Page. Only Administrate Role can see this list.

Answer (score 1):

Woocommerce customers are just regular WordPress users, so you can use the standard [`get_users()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) function.

You can pass the argument `role` to that, so something like...

`$customers = get_users( 'role=customer' );`

Answer (score 0):

I get it using this code

```
$args = array(
    'role' => 'dealer1'
);
$users = get_users($args);
if( empty($users) )
  return;
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?